# why my .rb script isn't putting to bash?

Tags: ruby, bash

I've got a simple code for a class. It's:

```
def greeting
 greeting = ARGV.shift
  ARGV.each do |arg|
     p "#{greeting}, #{arg}!"
     end
  end
```

My desire is for it to simply output "Hello, Charlie!" and "Hello, Sam!" based on the names stored in the array. However when I try to run the program in ruby it looks like I used a return statement.

```
 address_bloc :> ls
 address_bloc.rb greeting.rb     ruby
 argv_test.rb    models          spec

 address_bloc :> greeting.rb Yo Tommy Bob Sally
 -bash: greeting.rb: command not found

 address_bloc :> ruby greeting.rb Yo Sam Sean Bill

 address_bloc :> ruby greeting.rb Yo Sam Sean Bill
```

Comment: Looks like you defined a function `greeting()` but never called it.  Add `greeting()` to the end of the script, and you should get output.

Comment: Works! Thanks Michael!

Comment: To run a Ruby script from your shell, you need to 1) insert `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` as the first line, 2) change the file's permission to include executable (`chmod +x greeting.rb`), and 3) include the directory when you run it (`./greeting.rb`).

Answer (score 4):

Remove the function definition logic and just include the contents at the top-level if this is all you want your script to do:

```
greeting = ARGV.shift
ARGV.each do |arg|
  puts "#{greeting}, #{arg}!"
end
```

If you want to continue with defining a general-purpose function for greeting a list of names, you may also do so by calling `greeting` and passing it the contents of `ARGV`, as in the following:

```
def greeting(args)
  greeting = args.shift
  args.each do |arg|
    puts "#{greeting}, #{arg}!"
  end
end
greeting ARGV
```

But in general, it's a nicer function if its arguments are more meaningful, so consider doing something like this:

```
def greet_list(greeting, name_list)
  name_list.each do |arg|
    puts "#{greeting}, #{arg}!"
  end
end
greet_list ARGV.shift, ARGV
```

Comment: just to clarify. those following the call statement at the end "ARGV.shift," and "ARGV" work as filters for the arguments feeding into the method? Thank you!

Comment: @Sean Something like that. Basically it sets `greeting` in the method to the value of `ARGV.shift` (the first argument to the script). Then it sets `name_list` to all the remaining values of `ARGV`. That way, inside the `greet_list` function, you don't have to include that extra line `greeting = ARGV.shift`; it's already taken care of for you.